# Spellcheck form fields before submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, spell-checking

I'm trying to warn the users of spelling errors before they submit a form.
I'm looking for a solution that hopefully will highlight the misspelled word in an input, textarea or richtextarea(CKeditor) field or at least give me a reference so I can highlight the field with the error in it.

I'm currently looking at [this option](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com). I also saw [an alternative](http://www.webspellchecker.net), but it looks expensive.

Any other decent solutions, maybe a server solution that I can query using Ajax?

Comment: Doesn't everyone who really cares about spell checking already have a browser plugin for it? Not sure what your requirements are, but I think you should be really sure that you need to enforce spell checking, it could easily be annoying to some users.

Comment: That's what I said! I can even try to detect if a plugin is available and point the user to install it if it's not already.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can look into this:

http://developer.dictionary.com/products/spelling

they have a free api.

you could submit all your text to your ajax backend, send over each word to the api and get back spelling suggestions. from that you can probably figure out if the word is spelled wrong. At that point either return rendered html back, or a json object with indexes of misspelled words and suggestions